# Filter a table column by current logged user (IBM maximo)

Tags: dialog, maximo

i have this issue now in maximo:
i am currently developing a dialog over a copied wotrack application, on dialog window there is a table with a relation to asset table that show a list of assets by some criteria on relationship whereclause, i need to filter by a personid column on table, but this must be by a default value of current logged user, ¿How can i set the current logged user on a default value?, is this posible to get the current logged user as default value in application designer?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a Default Value control of Type=Query and Value=&USERNAME& and bound to the Table Column. If that doesn't work, you might be looking at a "Bean" customization.

Comment: I tryed that and it just place &USERNAME& on filter field, it not replace the value for current user. Maybe i must use Bean customization option then.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the relation in database configuration for the displayed table in dialog with adding this `:&personid&` for logged in user's personid

e.g

```
assetnum=:assetnum and siteid=:siteid and personid=:&personid&
```